# Is there a way for viewing the recent expensive queries in Sql Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I recently found out about the activity monitor in *SQL Server 2008* (I know, duh, right?). The tab "recent expensive queries" helped me quite a lot.

Now I'm trying to debug an overuse of the database in one client, but the server there is *SQL Server 2005*. There is an Activity Monitor there, but not "recent expensive queries" !

There are just three tabs: Process info, Locks by process and locks by object. The first one changes a lot and I am not being able to track the performance issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can view recent expensive queries with this... I use it all the time, it has far more detail than Activity Monitor.

NB: This is for cached plans only.

```
SELECT TOP 10 SUBSTRING(qt.TEXT, (qs.statement_start_offset/2)+1,
((CASE qs.statement_end_offset
WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(qt.TEXT)
ELSE qs.statement_end_offset
END - qs.statement_start_offset)/2)+1),
qs.execution_count,
qs.total_logical_reads, qs.last_logical_reads,
qs.total_logical_writes, qs.last_logical_writes,
qs.total_worker_time,
qs.last_worker_time,
qs.total_elapsed_time/1000000 total_elapsed_time_in_S,
qs.last_elapsed_time/1000000 last_elapsed_time_in_S,
qs.last_execution_time,
qp.query_plan
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) qt
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) qp
--ORDER BY qs.total_logical_reads DESC -- logical reads
--ORDER BY qs.total_logical_writes DESC -- logical writes
ORDER BY qs.total_worker_time DESC -- CPU time
```

[Source](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/05/14/sql-server-find-most-expensive-queries-using-dmv/)

Comment: It showed this error:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Comment: Yes, I copied it right. Maybe I don't have the right permissions? Apparently the error is thrown in this line: CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) qt

Comment: You need the "view server state" permission to use the dmv's above.  I'm not sure if that is the cause however.

Comment: Is there a easy way for me to know if I have this permission? I am not the server admin. But thanks anyway, when I get the permission, this query will be very helpful!

Comment: I do not know off the top of my head, sorry... maybe Google that permission name?

Comment: I found out! I have to run this query in the master database. Then the error doesn't happen =). Thank you JiggsJedi!

Comment: The Db you were trying it on was in SQL2000 mode

Comment: Hi this is really useful but I'm not confident with my cross/outer apply joins. How do I correctly join this to sys.dm_exec_requests and sys.dm_exec_sessions to get a session login_name so I can tell who is running the query? I've tried a couple of joins but it just hangs..