# SQL Server user query history

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to run a query that pulls a user(s) query history to determine long running queries. This information will be pulled every 5-10 minutes and stored in a table for a weekly report to run against showing the top 10 longest running queries.

I was able to find the below query and then add 'SYS.DM_EXEC_SESSIONS' which appears to returning what I need.  However, it seems like it's not a history but only active sessions.  I definitely need the user name, host name and database as part of the result set.

```
SELECT
r.session_id
,   s.login_name
,   s.host_name
,   r.start_time
,   TotalElapsedTime_ms = r.total_elapsed_time
,   r.[status]
,   s.program_name
,   r.command
,   DatabaseName = DB_Name(r.database_id)
,   r.cpu_time
,   r.reads
,   r.writes
,   r.logical_reads
,   t.[text] AS [executing batch]
,   SUBSTRING(
            t.[text], r.statement_start_offset / 2, 
            (   CASE WHEN r.statement_end_offset = -1 THEN DATALENGTH (t.[text]) 
                     ELSE r.statement_end_offset 
                END - r.statement_start_offset ) / 2 
         ) AS [executing statement] 
FROM
sys.dm_exec_requests r
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
sys.dm_exec_sessions s
ON
r.session_id = s.session_id
CROSS APPLY
sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) AS t
CROSS APPLY 
sys.dm_exec_query_plan(r.plan_handle) AS p
ORDER BY 
r.total_elapsed_time DESC;
```

So far I was able to pull session information from `SYS.DM_EXEC_SESSIONS` but I can't seem to find any views to link with for query statistics. The database is SQL Server 2012 SP1.

Any guidance/help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way for viewing the recent expensive queries in Sql Server 2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24896483/is-there-a-way-for-viewing-the-recent-expensive-queries-in-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 0):

That is what you are looking for?

```
SELECT  loginame AS LoginName ,
        sqltext.TEXT ,
        req.session_id ,
        req.status ,
        req.command ,
        req.cpu_time ,
        req.total_elapsed_time
FROM    sys.dm_exec_requests req
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqltext
        JOIN sys.sysprocesses s ON s.spid = session_id;
```

Comment: I was able to find the below query online and then added the sys.dm_exec_sessions view:

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into plan cache. It contains statistics about all those plans that are in the cache right now, so it should contain most of the recent expensive queries, and also quite a lot of older ones too. You can do it with something like this:

```
select top 100
SUBSTRING(t.text, (s.statement_start_offset/2)+1,
((CASE s.statement_end_offset
WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(t.text)
ELSE s.statement_end_offset
END - s.statement_start_offset)/2) + 1) as statement_text,
t.text,
s.total_logical_reads, 
s.total_logical_reads / s.execution_count as avg_logical_reads,
s.total_worker_time,
s.total_worker_time / s.execution_count as avg_worker_time,
s.execution_count,
creation_time,
last_execution_time
--,cast(p.query_plan as xml) as query_plan
from sys.dm_exec_query_stats s
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text (sql_handle) t
--cross apply sys.dm_exec_text_query_plan (plan_handle, statement_start_offset, statement_end_offset) p
order by s.total_logical_reads desc
```

That's just a sample that shows top 100 statements by logical reads. The commented part is for including query plans.

Comment: I was able to find one and then added a LEFT OUTER JOIN to the sys.dm_exec_requests table with sys.dm_exec_sessions. It seems to returning what I need but only active sessions?